# Weird streching of a texture in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, textures, rendering, rendertexture

Here is the problem: I'm rendering a red triangle in an offscreen Frame Buffer Object. I have a texture of that Buffer, and i'm applying this texture to a Simple rectangle(at runtime).

I get This result:
[image: The rectangle is showing what the other buffer is rendering]

This is exactly what i wanted. the problem is that when i strech my window the texture gets a little weird:

[image: The texture seems to be moving to the right while streching the window]

Just for curiosity i tried to render the rectangle without the texture.

[image: Here it looks fine]

And then I stretched the window once again:

[image: The rect is kind of following the window while it's beeing stretched]

I believe this is happening because in my default FBO I am setting glViewport to glViewport(0,0,m_Width,m_Height); (m_Width and m_Height are the dimensions of the Window)

Comment: I forgot to say i am using glfw as the windowing api. About glViewport, i am setting it every frame. Maybe this happens because i don't have a projection matrix of any sort..

Comment: if you don't have projection matrix, it defaults to -1 to 1 and your rectangle, of course, automatically follow that if you didn't update the rectangle coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is correct. Every time you resize your window, make sure both of your `glViewport()` and projection matrix are up to date. In SFML it would be something like this:

```
while (running) {
    sf::Event e;
    while (wind.pollEvent(e)) {
        switch (e.type) {
        // ...
        case sf::Event::Resized:
            glViewport(0, 0, e.size.width, e.size.height);

            // Set your projection matrix here
            // Will be different from one library to the other

            break;
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```